# Javascript not removing all elements within a div

Tags: javascript, html, removechild

This piece of javascript code is created to remove all inputs that are within a div

```
function remove_inputs(){
   var elements=document.getElementById('thediv').getElementsByTagName('input');
   for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
       elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
   }
}
```

I does remove only half of elements a call and I have to call it several times in order to remove all inputs.

Please check this **[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wNkf/)** to see it in action.

Comment: `elements.length` is evaluated every loop iteration. That's the problem.

Try saving the `elements.length` on a variable and use this variable on the `for` loop.

Comment: @HugoHidekiYamashita no, that's not the problem. If you remove item 0, item 1 becomes item 0.

Comment: @dystroy sorry, I hadn't realized that.

Comment: You didn't accept any answer. Is there a problem ?

Comment: @dystroy sorry. I tried to accept yours but stackoverflow did't allow me to accept saying I have to wait (users here have to wait 10 min to accept one answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you skip items while removing from the [live nodelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

When you remove the item at index 0, the item which was at index 1 takes index 0, so you don't remove it as your iteration is already on index 1.

Do it like this :

```
function remove_inputs(){
   var elements=document.getElementById('thediv').getElementsByTagName('input');
   while(elements.length){
       elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
   }
}
```

Comment: May I offer a demo: [http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9wNkf/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9wNkf/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use jQuery instead?

```
function remove_inputs(){
   var elements = $('#thediv input');
   elements.remove();
}
```

Here is more information: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: Please, don't recommend the use of a huge library just for this simple task.

Comment: JQuery is so universal it is almost always appropriate to provide a solution using it if just for any search engine results that lead to the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
function remove_inputs(){
   var elements = document.getElementById('thediv').getElementsByTagName('input');
   var size = elements.length;

   for(var i = 0; i < size; i++){
       elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
   }
}
```