# removeChild(); not removing all items from list

Tags: javascript

When I run the following code, half of the items are removed from the list.. I am trying to remove all items from the list.

```
  //Sets an event listener to the reset button.
  resetButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
      console.log(ul.children.length);

      //Moves through the unordered list and removes each list item.
      for(let i = 0; i < ul.children.length; i++) {
        ul.removeChild(ul.children[i]);
      }
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript not removing all elements within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410450/javascript-not-removing-all-elements-within-a-div)

Comment: You are modifying the list over which you are iterating - that leads to the observed issues. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript for a solution.

Comment: Have you tried `for(let i = ul.children.length ; i>= 0;i++)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code seemingly seems random is due to:

```
for(let i = 0; i < ul.children.length; i++) {
    ul.removeChild(ul.children[i]);
}
```

As you are removing elements from the UL, it's children length is getting smaller so `ul.children.length` is reducing from n, to n-1, to n-2 etc.  However, your `i` is increasing.  Eventually, `i` will be larger than `ul.children.length` even thought there children left over. As `i` increases, your children in UL is getting smaller, however you are removing from the 0 first.  So it means you will also eventually be attempting to remove elements which doesn't exist, as they are now in [0].

I modified your code to this following:

```
document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const ul = document.getElementById("myUL");

  while (ul.children[0]) {
    ul.removeChild(ul.children[0])
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, so using ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild); should work too, correct?

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over a list and inside the iteration you are manipulating the list removing elements. This is causing the issue.

For removing all the elements inside your node you can simply do:

```
document.getElementById("myUL").innerHTML = '';
```

Otherwise if you like loops for some reason, do that:

```
var el = document.getElementById("myUL");
while (el.firstChild) {
   el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do so, the code would be even more compact

jquery solution

```
  //Sets an event listener to the reset button.
  resetButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const ul = document.getElementById("myUL");

      $(ul).empty();

  });
```

This function removes all the children of the father object

```
 .empty();
```

html standard solution

```
  //Sets an event listener to the reset button.
  resetButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const ul = document.getElementById("myUL");

      ul.innerHTML ="";

  });
```

This variable represents the html content of the parent object

```
.innerHTML =""
```

Comment: `const ul = document.getElementById("myUL"); $(ul).empty();` can simply be `$("#myUL").empty();`